# TinyMCE is not a function

Tags: javascript, tinymce, runtime-error

I'm using the TinyMCE html editor and I am getting this error

> tinymce is not a function

I'm adding the appropriate files in my layout page (the first 2 items at the top of the page)

```
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js")> type="text/javascript"</script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")> type="text/javascript"</script>
```

and I'm initiating the editor like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  initEditor();
});


function initEditor() {
  var myForm = $('#frmDetails');
  //the underlying contents are placed in a hidden field
  //unobtrusive validation ignores hidden fields, this tells validation to include them
  $.data(myForm[0], 'validator').settings.ignore = "null";
  tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    //selector: 'textarea',
    //strict_loading_mode :true,
    branding: false,
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "modern",
    height: "350px",
    width: "100%",
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | fontselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | print preview",
    font_formats: 'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats',
    schema: "html5",
    content_css: 'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    //this makes clientside validation work
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('keyUp', function () {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(myForm.validate().submitted))
        myForm.validate().form();
      });
    },
    paste_as_text: true,
    relative_urls: false
  });
};
```

yet I still get the error.  What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `document.ready()` is running that function before the TinyMCE scripts have finished loading.  From the jQuery documentation I find this:

> Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

If you switch to `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` does the error regarding tinymce not being a function go away?

Comment: After the page is fully loaded - if you open your browser console can you access the `tinymce` variable?

Comment: I figured it out eventually, I had an editor template setup that was referencing a tinymce javascript file that didnt actually exist in my project, changing the reference solved it, although i wasnt actually using the editor template anywhere

Comment: how do I access the tinymce variable?

Comment: sory m being dumb, yes I can acces it now